# Берется ли в кавычки слово "мыльница"?

Tags: жаргон, пунктуация

Когда речь идет о фотоаппарате, нужно ли брать в кавычки слово "мыльница"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
слово *мыльница* в значении "фотоаппарат" не требует кавычек.

Answer (score 2):

Известно,что одним из неморфологических способов словообразования является развитие нового значения у существующих в языке слов. Слово "мыльница" в значении "фотоаппарат определенной формы и конструкции" может претендовать на такую трансформацию в будущем, но пока что оно воспринимается как слово, употребляемое в переносном значении и даже с некоторым скептическим оттенком, поэтому должно браться в кавычки

Comment: Извините, пожалуйста, что комментирую Ваш ответ. Просто в своем ответе добавить свои комментарии для продолжения дискуссии нет возможности.
По "мыльнице"... А почему бы тогда не припомнить "Лилипут" или "Ученик", котрые выпускались еще в 30-е годы прошлого века? Я еще в 70-е фотокружок посещал со Сменой-8М - и в мыслях ни у кого не было "мыльницей" назвать, да и вообще это слово применительно к фотоаппаратам не применялось тогда. Это все 80-е годы, когда в комиссионках появились привезенные "оттуда" "мыльницы" с доморощенными переводами к инструкциям. К сож., на отв. по лаптопам не хват. симв

Comment: tmp, к сожалению, какие-то технические особенности этого форума не позволяют мне вести диалог в одной ветке, поэтому вынужден отвечать здесь, да и подробно изложить точку зрения - не хватает символов.
По "soap-size" - это не мне оно полюбилось. Насчет изобретения этого "термина" русскими (а русскими ли?) коммерсантами не скажу, но то, что в англоязычном сегменте оно употребляется редко, вполне понятно, так как абсолютно безграмотно. Вы вот заявили, что использовали "мыльницу" в 70-е, и это было на слуху - на слуху у кого?
Где мне отвечать на тему лаптопов - понятия не имею...

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не стал относить это слово к устоявшимся жаргонизмам. Слишком оно молодое по отношению к фотоаппаратам - это раз. И скоро сойдет на нет - это два, учитывая тенденции развития техники. Поэтому - в кавычки.
Слову (в русском языке, разумеется) лэптоп (лаптоп) всего-то лет 25, а кто его сейчас помнит?

Comment: Оно более чем древняя для жаргонизма. Жаргонизмы живут в среднем лет тридцать, а мыльнице - под пятьдесят.

Comment: Сильно в этом сомневаюсь. Особенно по части массового употребления.

Comment: В чем именно? Я не вижу тут никаких разговоров о "массовом употреблении" вообще. А по срокам - не сомневайтесь. Первой советской мыльницей был "Нарцисс-К" (в девичестве - LeiKa), 1964 г.
  
Кстати, слово лэптоп изначально было мертворожденным, поскольку не соответствовало значению в английском, откуда оно было якобы заимствовано.

Comment: Да что Вы говорите? А понятие "soap-sized camera", откуда, собственно говоря, и пошло тупо переведенное название иностранного жаргонизма, Вам неизвестно?

Comment: Уважаемый Тимур Казимиров!
Мне известно понятие "soap-sized camera". 







Comment: А когда оно оттуда пошло? Здесь же вопрос о русском языке.

Comment: Что слову "мыльница" в русском языке, применительно к фотоаппаратам, лет 50. Это неверно. Гораздо моложе. Он же сопоставляет появление самого подобного аппарата с появлением в языке жаргонизма.
Про лэптоп Бегемотус, кстати, тоже ерунду несет. Особенно про "якобы".

Comment: Dolcentl, во второй половине 80-х.

Comment: Что-то не помню. Может, в Москве. У нас, в провинции - позже.

Comment: По мыльнице откомментировал другой ответ. Теперь по лаптопам. Появились они в СССР раньше и назывались лаптопами и означал термин именно то, что означает это слово в английском языке (для меня это 1977 год). Другой вопрос, что это было не массовое, а узкопрофессиональное употребление. А вот когда это слово вошло в массы, практически одновременно с ним появилось слово "ноутбук", точно также, как и неуклюжие попытки в первых компьютерных пособиях и журналах дать отличия одного от другого. Вот и привилось мнение, что лаптоп - это что-то громоздкое и неуклюжее, хоть и переносное.

Comment: Вот что значит Москва и "элитная" школа. У нас в провинции все произошло позже. Думаю, и среди москвичей не все в то время видели такие "игрушки". Так что массовым и всем понятным словом оно стало гораздо позже.  

Впрочем, о чем тут копья ломать? Вы еще пейджер вспомните ))) На последней новогодней вечеринке я вообще снимала планшетом. Кстати, а для него какого-нибудь смешной термин не придумали?